# How to uncheck a fragment in navigation drawer when we move to another fragment

Tags: android

**in my app once i check the item from the navigation drawer it is remaining checked and is not unchecked even if I click on other menu item**

Comment: you have to code for that.

Comment: post your code here..

Comment: What are you using fragments for? are they fragments for view pager?

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck all menu Items used this method,

```
 private void uncheckAllMenuItems(NavigationView navigationView) {
    final Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        if (item.hasSubMenu()) {
            SubMenu subMenu = item.getSubMenu();
            for (int j = 0; j < subMenu.size(); j++) {
                MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem(j);
                subMenuItem.setChecked(false);
            }
        } else {
            item.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```